# InvalidArgumentError when running model.fit()

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

When I run the below code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),input_shape = X.shape[1:],data_format = "channels_last"))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))    
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam',loss = 'binary_crossentropy',metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, epochs=1,
    validation_split=0.3)
```

I'm getting:

> InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         3           batch_size=32,
>         4           epochs=1,
>   ----> 5           validation_split=0.3)
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py
>   in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks,
>   validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight,
>   sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps,
>   **kwargs)    1361           initial_epoch=initial_epoch,    1362           steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
>   -> 1363           validation_steps=validation_steps)    1364     1365   def evaluate(self,
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py
>   in fit_loop(model, inputs, targets, sample_weights, batch_size,
>   epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_inputs, val_targets,
>   val_sample_weights, shuffle, callback_metrics, initial_epoch,
>   steps_per_epoch, validation_steps)
>       262           ins_batch[i] = ins_batch[i].toarray()
>       263 
>   --> 264         outs = f(ins_batch)
>       265         if not isinstance(outs, list):
>       266           outs = [outs]
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py in
>   **call**(self, inputs)    2910         feed_symbols != self._feed_symbols or self.fetches != self._fetches or    2911
>   session != self._session):
>   -> 2912       self._make_callable(feed_arrays, feed_symbols, symbol_vals, session)    2913     2914     fetched =
>   self._callable_fn(*array_vals)
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py in
>   _make_callable(self, feed_arrays, feed_symbols, symbol_vals, session)    2855     callable_opts.target.append(self.updates_op.name)    2856
>
> ## Create callable.
>
> -> 2857     callable_fn = session._make_callable_from_options(callable_opts)    2858     # Cache
>   parameters corresponding to the generated callable, so that    2859
>
> ## we can detect future mismatches and refresh the callable.
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in
>   _make_callable_from_options(self, callable_options)    1412     """    1413     self._extend_graph()
>   -> 1414     return BaseSession._Callable(self, callable_options)    1415     1416
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in
>   **init**(self, session, callable_options)    1366         with errors.raise_exception_on_not_ok_status() as status:    1367
>   self._handle = tf_session.TF_SessionMakeCallable(
>   -> 1368               session._session, options_ptr, status)    1369       finally:    1370         tf_session.TF_DeleteBuffer(options_ptr)
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py
>   in **exit**(self, type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)
>       517             None, None,
>       518             compat.as_text(c_api.TF_Message(self.status.status)),
>   --> 519             c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
>       520     # Delete the underlying status object from memory otherwise it stays alive
>       521     # as there is a reference to status from this from the traceback due to
>
> InvalidArgumentError: Default MaxPoolingOp only supports NHWC on
>   device type CPU    [[Node: max_pooling2d_2/MaxPool =
>   MaxPoolT=DT_FLOAT,
>   _class=["loc:@training_3/Adam/gradients/max_pooling2d_2/MaxPool_grad/MaxPoolGrad"],
>   data_format="NCHW", ksize=[1, 1, 2, 2], padding="VALID", strides=[1,
>   1, 2, 2],
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

## X.shape ----> (8000, 50, 50, 1)

Also I'm using 4GB RAM CPU. I've run only on one epoch. Does this have anything to do with the memory?

Comment: Could it be because of `=` missing after metrics?

Comment: and can you let us know more like system spec and backend of keras being used?

Comment: that's a typo here.. Not the cause of error

Comment: I'm using tensorflow

Comment: Please include the code of your model in the question, its about channel ordering, not memory.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro .. I've added it

Comment: Why do you need to add data format to channels last in the first layer? Does it work without it?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I get ValueError when I don't use data_format. Earlier I've changed the data_format in keras(.json) file to channels_first. So, I'm adding channels_last in the code here

Comment: Well! It works fine now.. I've changed the data_format in.json to channels_last. Thanks @MatiasValdenegro